# Escaped character on Telegram Bot API 4.5 MarkdownV2 gives trouble for hyper link

Tags: regex, replace, escaping, telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram **Bot API 4.5** comes with new parse mode, MarkdownV2. At the same time these `_ * [ ] ( ) ~ > # + - = | { } . !` characters must be escaped with the preceding character `\`.

`.replace(/[-.+?^$[\](){}\\]/g, '\\$&')` used as solution for adding escape character which works very well but unfortunately this solution does effect hyperlink method `[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)` because it replace `\[inline URL\]\(http://www.example\.com/\)`

**Solution**

```
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
  const { chat } = ctx.message;
  const msgs = `Here is the [rules](https://telegra.ph/rules-05-06) Please read carefully and give the details which mentioned below.
*Name:*
*Place:*
*Education:*
*Experience:*
You can also call me on (01234567890)
__For premium service please contact with admin__`;

  const msgmsgWithEscape = msgs.replace(/[-.+?^$[\](){}\\]/g, '\\$&')

  ctx.telegram.sendMessage(
    chat.id,
    msgmsgWithEscape,
    {
      parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2',
    }
  )
});
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To avoid escaping links formatted like `[...](http...)` you may match them and capture into a group and just match all the chars to escape in other contexts. Then, examine the Group 1 value and if it is not empty, replace with Group 1 value, else, replace with the escaped char:

```js
const msgs = `Here is the [rules](https://telegra.ph/rules-05-06) Please read carefully and give the details which mentioned below.
*Name:*
*Place:*
*Education:*
*Experience:*
You can also call me on (01234567890)
__For premium service please contact with admin__`;

const msgmsgWithEscape = msgs.replace(/(\[[^\][]*]\(http[^()]*\))|[_*[\]()~>#+=|{}.!-]/gi,
    (x,y) => y ? y : '\\' + x)

console.log(msgmsgWithEscape);
```

Comment: You should add a **!** and **#** to the regExp:   '_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')', '~', '\`', '>', '#', '+', '-', '=', '|', '{', '}', '.', '!' must be escaped

Comment: @LeeTwelve I thought the main trouble was matching those chars outside strings within brackets, but you are right. I added the missing chars.

Comment: You should add a step of preprocessing the titles of the links. Something along the lines `msgmsgWithEscape  = msgmsgWithEscape.replace(/\[([^\][]*)]\(/g, (x,y) => "[" + y.replace(/[-.+?^$[\](){}\\!#]/g, '\\$&') + "]\(" );`