# How can I escape characters (, ), [, ], *, _, with \ without changing link construction: []()

Tags: c#, regex, markdown

I have the following text:

```cs
input = "text, *text*, text, text, (text), [text], [text](http://.....) *text*, text, text, (text), [text]"
```

I'm trying to replace characters '_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')' to '\_', '\*' etc.

I'm writing:

```cs
pattern = @"(?<!\[(?<text>.*)\]\((?<url>.*))([[\]\(\)*_])";

input = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, @"\$1");

System output: "text, \*text\*, text, text, \(text\), \[text\], \[some\_text with \_ \* \]\(http://.....) \*text\*, text, text, \(text\), \[text\]"
```

How to make sure that the design of the link []() doesn't change? i.e. it would look like:

```cs
desired output:"text, \*text\*, text, text, \(text\), \[text\], [some\_text with \_ \*](http://.....) \*text\*, text, text, \(text\), \[text\]"
```

Comment: Is your regex matching all the chars you need to escape? Is it related to [Escaped character on Telegram Bot API 4.5 MarkdownV2 gives trouble for hyper link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130062/escaped-character-on-telegram-bot-api-4-5-markdownv2-gives-trouble-for-hyper-lin?)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I didn’t write all the characters, because I tried to solve the problem with the link, but I don't quite understand how to solve it. I tried: (? <! \ [(? <text>. *) \] \ ((? <url>. *)) ([| * {} # + = \ -_.! ~> `]), but it still worked like this: \ [... \\] \ (url \\)

Comment: Please format the question with backticks around your code. It is not clear what is escaped and what is not. Check my example edit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I fixed the format, thanks for the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match and capture the markdown link part, and just match the chars you need to escape, and then use a match evaluator in the replacement part:

```cs
var input = "text, *text*, text, text, (text), [text], [some_text with _*](http://.....) *text*, text, text, (text), [text]";
var pattern = @"(\[[^][]*]\([^()]*\))|[][()*_]";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => 
    m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : $@"\{m.Value}"));
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/rHlZ11). *Details*:

- `(\[[^][]*]\([^()]*\))` - Capturing group 1 matching `[`, then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` (with `[^][]*`), then a `]` char, `(`, then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` (with `[^()]*`) and then a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `[][()*_]` - a character class that matches: `]` (note it is not escaped because it is the first char in the character class), `[`, `(`, `)`, `*` or `_` chars.

The `m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : $@"\{m.Value}"` replacement replaces the match found with Group 1 value if Group 1 matched, else, the replacement is the match value (the special char defined in the character class) with a `\` prepended.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot, but for example, if the text for the link has the same signs, how can they be escaped, [Hello_World*](url) ([Hello\_World\*](url)?

Comment: @di_va Then use `var pattern = @"\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)|[][()*_]";` and then `m => m.Groups[1].Success ? $@"[{Regex.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, @"[()_*]", @"\$&")}]({Regex.Replace(m.Groups[2].Value, @"[()_*]", @"\$&")})" : $@"\{m.Value}")`

Comment: Can I ask a question? I put into [text - # { }  ](url) characters: `#`, `{`, `}` `-` but it doesn't escaped it, why? And added this character into pattern

Comment: @di_va It depends where you "put" it. It must be `[][()*_-]`.

Comment: I put it in last structure [][(){}*_|#+=.!\-~>] but they didn't ecsaped

Comment: @di_va At this point, I do not not see an issue. Please share a [link to C# demo](https://ideone.com/rHlZ11).

Comment: In the title of the link, I inserted characters that need to be escaped, but they are not escaped and that is an issue [link](https://ideone.com/odbdMP)

Comment: I found my mistake, sorry, I'm just new to regex

Comment: @di_va Right, the pattern must be something like `@"\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)|[][(){}*_|#+=.!~>-]"` and then inside the match evaluator, it must be `@"[][(){}*_|#+=.!~>-]"` ([demo](https://ideone.com/h8RvMI)).